# Why is there an infinite loop at the end of do_exit() defined in kernel/exit.c?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel, I am confused about the purpose of having the loop at the end of [do_exit()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/exit.c).

Isn't the call to schedule() the last code that will be ever executed by do_exit()..?

```
666 void do_exit(long code)
667 {
668         struct task_struct *tsk = current;
669         int group_dead;
670 
671         ..........

833         /* causes final put_task_struct in finish_task_switch(). */
834         tsk->state = TASK_DEAD;
835         tsk->flags |= PF_NOFREEZE;      /* tell freezer to ignore us */
836         schedule();
837         BUG();
838         /* Avoid "noreturn function does return".  */
839         for (;;)
840                 cpu_relax();    /* For when BUG is null */
841 }
842
```

Comment: Technically yes, schedule will most likely be the last call made (since it will generally never return). The loop is there for pretty much one reason - to avoid the gcc compiler from throwing this warning `volatile function does return` . According to the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnoreturn_007d-function-attribute-2626) a function marked as volatile void will never return. The loop prevents it from returning thus avoiding the compiler complaining.

Comment: If you were to edit your question and provide the code from `exit.c` for the `do_exit()` function and ask why the loop exists, the question may fend off the potential downvotes and close votes. I could then provide an official answer. At the moment it is a waste for me to create an answer only to see this question disappear.

Comment: it is a bit long code, that's why I didn't add it.

Comment: I have added the code that has the infinite for loop.

Comment: There is, or perhaps just used to be, a comment somewhere around this code explaining that `schedule()` doesn't ever return *when `tsk->state == TASK_DEAD`*, which is too subtle for the compiler to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the kernel it may appear differently but generally the structure is the same.

In some implementations it starts with:

```
NORET_TYPE void do_exit(long code)
```

NORET_TYPE may be different across varying **GCC** compilers (it may be an attribute that marks a no return function) or it may be `volatile`.  What does such a declaration on a function do? It effectively says *I won't return*. You can find more about it in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnoreturn_007d-function-attribute-2626) which says:

> The attribute noreturn is not implemented in GCC versions earlier than 2.5. An alternative way to declare that a function does not return, which works in the current version and in some older versions, is as follows:
>
> ```
>      typedef void voidfn ();         
>      volatile voidfn fatal;
> ```

`volatile void` functions are non-conforming extensions to the C standard created by the GCC developers. You won't find it in the ANSI C Standard (C89).

It happens to be when the kernel reaches `do_exit()` it doesn't intend to return from the function.Generally it will block indefinitely or until something resets the system (usually). The problem is that if you mark a function as `not returning` the compiler will warn you if your function exits. So you generally see an infinite loop of some sort (a `while`, `for`, `goto` etc). In your case it does:

```
/* Avoid "noreturn function does return".  */
for (;;)
```

Interestingly enough the comment pretty much gives the reason. `noreturn function does return` is a gcc compiler warning. an infinite loop that is obvious to the compiler (like `for (;;)`) is enough to stop the compiler from complaining as it it will determine that the function can't reach a point where it can exit.

Even if there is no compiler warning to worry about the infinite loop prevents the function from returning. At some point a kernel (not necessarily Linux) is going to be faced with fact that it was called by a `jmp` instruction to get it started (At least on x86 systems). Often the `jmp` is used to set the code segment for entering protected mode or at the most basic level the BIOS jumps to the code that loads the boot sector (in very simple OSes). This means that there is a finite end to the code and to prevent the processor from executing invalid instructions it is better to make it busy doing nothing of interest.

The code `cpu_relax();    /* For when BUG is null */` is to fix a kernel bug. It is mentioned in this [post my Linus](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/1/28/110)

```
sched: Fix ancient race in do_exit()
```